# Monitoring Azure File Storage Containers and Shares

Tags: c#, python, .net, azure, azure-storage

I am attempting to write a script or program of some sort to query azure file storage containers for their total disk usage as well as some other data, the disk usage is absolutely needed currently.

I've been reading documentation on the Azure site, and am unable to come up with a clear plan. I've also browsed some forums including stackoverflow. However, I'm still facing the same issue. I would prefer to use python, I understand that there is an Azure python sdk, but C#/.NET would also be doable.

Can anyone provide any insight into this process, or has anyone had any experience with their own monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with Azure Blob storage, you cannot query usage for an individual container, aside from enumerating all blobs in the container and tallying each blob's size (which is fairly straightforward to do, except it could take a while with a large number of blobs).

You *can* query the total storage used across all blobs, through storage analytics metrics:

- Look at at the `$MetricsCapacityBlob` table.
- There is a `Capacity` column, representing total capacity used, in bytes
- There are `ContainerCount` and `ObjectCount` properties as well, giving you total containers and total blobs (but just counts, not capacity)

You can query this table with Python, just as you'd query any other Azure Storage table.

Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343264.aspx) for more details on storage analytics.

Comment: I wanted to provide an update to this. I found after searching for a while, Azure CLI allows this. It took some work and formatting but I was able to write a script that checked storage accounts and their subsequent file shares for the space used.

Comment: Your original question only mentioned containers. It was unclear you were looking at the file service. For that, yes there is a "get stats" API call for a file share. I misunderstood your question.